# Problem in understanding mapping in Java Spring boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot

I have just started with Spring boot.
I have 3 tables User, UserNotes, and Notes.

1. User ( userID, EmailID)
2. UserNotes (UserID, NotesID)
3. Notes (notesID, Title, Message )

When I add an email, UserID has to be autogenerated. And when I add any note corresponding to the user, Notes Id in **UserNotes** table must be autogenerated and it must be added to **Notes** table.
I have done it in MySQL by making userID in **User** table as primary key and UserID in UserNotes as foreign key referencing to it. Similarly NotesID in **UserNotes** as primary key and notesID in **Notes** table as a foreign key for that.

Everything is working fine when I am using MySQL queries for this. But now I want to use Spring Data JPA for this. But I am facing difficulty in understanding how to map these relationships having multiple tables. I have tried **OneToMany** and **ManyToOne** relationship but it didn't work out

```
MySQL Queries for the reference  
1) Create table User(userID int AUTO_INCREMENT, emailID varchar(40), PRIMARY KEY(userID));  
2) Create table UserNotes(userID int, NotesID int AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(NotesID), Foreign key(UserID) references User(UserID) on DELETE CASCADE);  
3) Create table Notes(notesID int, title varchar(100), message varchar(500), Date date, PRIMARY KEY(notesID), FOREIGN KEY(notesID) references UserNotes(NotesID) on DELETE CASCADE);
```

Comment: You should read about different kind of entity relationships and specifically about ManyToMany relationship. The connecting table UserNote doesn’t generate anything, since these are foreign keys that it contains they have to be created in the corresponding tables first. In general I would advise you to read a book on sql since you need to understand some basics.

Answer (score 0):

An untested example using Hibernate, JPA, Lombok:

**User entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "userSeqId", sequenceName = "user_seq_id", allocationSize = 1)
@NoArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "userSeqId", strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "EMAIL", unique = true)
    private String email;
}
```

**Notes entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "NOTES")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "notesSeqId", sequenceName = "notes_seq_id", allocationSize = 1)
@NoArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
public class Notes {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "notesSeqId", strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "TITLE")
    private String title;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "MESSAGE")
    private String message;
}
```

**UserNotes entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_NOTES")
@NoArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
public class UserNotes {

    @EmbeddedId
    private UserNotesKey id;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("USER_ID")
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private User user;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @MapsId("NOTES_ID")
    @JoinColumn(name = "NOTES_ID")
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private Notes notes;
}

@Embeddable
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class UserNotesKey implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    private Long userId;

    @Column(name = "NOTES_ID")
    private Long notesId;
}
```

**Repositories**

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

}

public interface NotesRepository extends JpaRepository<Notes, Long> {

}

public interface UserNotesRepository extends JpaRepository<UserNotes, UserNotesKey> {

    List<UserNotes> findByUser(User user);
}
```

**Test service**

```
@Service
@Transactional
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TestService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final UserNotesRepository userNotesRepository;

    public User saveUser(User user) {
        User newUser = new User();
        user.setEmail(user.getEmail());
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }

    public UserNotes saveNotes(User user, Notes notes) {
        UserNotes userNotes = new UserNotes();
        userNotes.setUser(user);
        userNotes.setNotes(notes);
        return userNotesRepository.save(userNotes);
    }

    public List<Notes> getNotes(User user) {
        return userNotesRepository.findByUser(user)
                .stream()
                .map(UserNotes::getNotes)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```